# Confidence Interval for mle2 Regression Line

Tags: r

I am doing a non-linear regression with mle2 in R and I want to generate a 95% point-wise confidence band around the curve of best fit. A simplified example of what I am trying to do is shown below, where I try to use predict on the mle2 fit object. Any suggestions on how to do this?

```
library(bbmle)

# Fabricated data
e.u <- function( x, k ) { exp(-k * x) }
n <- 40
t.bio <- 1:n
bio <- 10*e.u(t.bio,log(2)/10) + rnorm(n,0,sqrt(e.u(t.bio,log(2)/10)))

#Use mle2 to estimate the parameters
intake.guess <- 10
rc.guess <- 0.07

n.log.like <- function(intake,k) {
  sum.y <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(bio)) {
    x <- intake * e.u(t.bio[i],k)
    y <- bio[i]
    sum.y <- sum.y + log( dnorm(y,x,0.1*sqrt(y)) ) }
  return(-sum.y)
}   

b <- mle2(n.log.like,
        start=list(
            intake=intake.guess,
            k=rc.guess),
        data=list(
            t.bio=t.bio,
            bio=bio),
        method="Nelder-Mead",
        skip.hessian=FALSE)

intake <- coef(summary(b))[1,1]         
rc <- coef(summary(b))[2,1]         
summary(b)

#Scatter plot
bio.p <- numeric(n)
x <- 1:n
for (i in 1:n) { bio.p[i] <- intake * e.u(x[i],rc) }
plot(x,bio.p,type="l",log="xy",main="",
     xlab="Days After Intake",ylab="Excretion")
points(t.bio,bio)

#I want to generate a confidence interval on the regression line
bio.hat <- predict(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this resource:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/predict.lm.html

There is a `se.fit` parameter passed with `predict()`. If `TRUE`, it will calculate the SE. I have not tried it.

Another way is to use the `library(ggplot2)`, which with one of the parameters you can get an Confidence Level overlayed on your plot automatically. An example,

```
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt))
c + stat_smooth(se = TRUE) + geom_point()
```

This will be put a band around the plot to indicate the confidence interval. `se` is set to TRUE by default.

Reference: 
http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/ggplot2/html/stat_smooth.html

Third, you may calculate the confidence interval and overlay the plot by setting par(new=TRUE). This may be cumbersome but still feasible.

Comment: this won't work so well for a generic MLE fit.  Bootstrapping is probably the easiest way to go unless the problem is really large/hard.

Comment: I ended up using the bootstrap as suggested by Ben Bolker.